# Monoid on any Foldable

Tags: haskell, monoids

I'm trying to make an instance of a Monoid on haskell, a monoid that can be applicable on any Foldable strutucture that contains comparables elements and returns the maximun value stored.

So far i have this

```
import Data.List
import Data.Functor
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Tree

newtype Max a = Max { getMax :: Maybe a}
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

instance Ord a => Monoid (Max a) where
   mempty = Max Nothing
   mappend (Max x) (Max y) = Max (max x y)
```

It works prefectly on list but have some issue with Trees. When i use it on void list it returns

```
ghci> foldMap (Max . Just) []
Max {getMax = Nothing}
```

And that's what i want, but when i use it on Trees with no elements

```
ghci> foldMap (Max . Just) (Node [] [])
Max {getMax = Just []}
```

But i want to it returns Nothing instead Just []. It doesn't opperate with Nodes with no childrens but it works with valued ones

```
ghci> foldMap (Max . Just) (Node 22 [Node 7 [Node 42 []], Node 18 [] ])
Max {getMax = Just 42}
```

Any suggestion?

PD: I'm using ghci 7.10

Comment: `Node [] []` isn't an empty tree, it's a single node with no children.

Comment: You need to clarify what tree type this is you're talking about.

Comment: This monoid is also available in [monoid-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.0.4/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html). A slight warning if you implement `Min` yourself instead of using this package: `mappend (Min x) (Min y) = Min (min x y)` is not quite right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Tree` type in `Data.Tree` does not support empty trees.  Ask GHCI what the type of `Node [] []` is and you'll find out something like this:

```
Node [] [] :: a => Tree [a]
```

Your monoid works fine.

Comment: but shouldn't apply same as lists withou elements?

Comment: That isn't a tree without elements.  That's a tree with one element, and the element is `[]`.

Comment: I don't think you will have a constraint (and also `a => Tree [a]` would be invalid because `a` cannot be a constraint in this context, even if `ConstraintKinds` are enabled)

Comment: @DavidYoung: Notice there's no class there.  That's just a tired brain thinking `forall a.` and writing `a =>` instead.